# How to stop Facebook SDK Dialog using white textcolor even if my theme needs white text

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

As much as I learn, I still have a long way to go ...

I'm trying to use Facebook SDK to provide details for a sign up.

I am using a blue, yellow and white theme for my app; the text being white. My style setup is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorMainBackground</item>
    <!--<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <!--<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>-->
    <!--<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?android:attr/statusBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

However, when Facebook shows a dialog box, all I get is a white square:

[image]

It would appear that Facebook are using my textcolor and hence the white box. Is there a way I can override this? Or have Facebook use the default colour scheme (if there is one).

This is somewhat frustrating me now.

My Manifest entry for Facebook is:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue. It seems FacebookActivity picks up the color from the style you declared in the application tag.

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme'>
```

You see it white because in styles.xml you have the accent color to white. for your theme.

```
<item name="colorAccent">#FFF</item>
```

Since in my application I need the colorAccent to be another color, I chose to have two AppThemes. One for my activities with whatever colorAccent I need and one for the application that will get used by Facebook.

I tried to add a theme to com.facebook.FacebookActivity but it gets ignored. Something to do with [ManifestMerging](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html).